# Directly annotate matplotlib stacked bar graph

Tags: matplotlib, formatting, bar-chart

I want to annotate a stacked bar graph using matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['year'] = ['2019','2020','2021','2022']
df = df.set_index('year')
df['test 1'] = [2,16,85,15]
df['test 1a'] = [16,18,9.5,0]
df['test 2'] = [16.5,15,31.5,24]
df['test 3'] = [13.5,34,37,205]
df['test 4'] = [12.5,10,42,96]
df['test 4a'] = [0,44,0,38]
df['test 4b'] = [6,3,8,0]
df['test 4c'] = [0,131,29.5,1]
df['test 5'] = [0,0,87,0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(9,4))
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax)

ax.annotate(xy=('2021',350), xycoords='data', text='revision')

plt.show()
```

The aim is to print `revision` above the `2021` bar like:

[image]

I tried using the `annotate` function but the `xy` argument doesn't accept the string `2021` as the x-coordinate. How do I fix this?

Comment: Internally, matplotlib uses the numbers `0,1,2,...` for the x positions. So, `ax.annotate(xy=(2,350), ...)` would work in your case.

Comment: thanks that works, do you want to post this as an answer below?